# Child to parent page refresh

Tags: wpf

I was wondering whether there's a way to trigger the parent page. For example, I have a drop down from the parent page, when I select an item, this will open up a "child", another window based on what I've selected. What I want to achieve here is, in the child window, I can select an item based on the the radio button and this should should automatically update the parent window to have the correct text. I dont know if this makes sense but I hope someone can understand where I'm getting at and try to help out if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a dependency property in your child class for the text to bind to. Then you can just bind to the selected item to access said property.

Here is somewhere to get started with that
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx

To take this further you could create a base control to put the depency property in that all your child controls would inherit from.

Edit
Base class

```
public class BaseExample : ContentControl
{
    public string BaseText
     {
         get { return (string)this.GetValue(BaseTextProperty); }
         set { this.SetValue(BaseTextProperty, value); } 
     }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"BaseText", typeof(string), typeof(BaseExample),new PropertyMetadata(false));  
}


public class child : BaseExample { }
```

from here you would inherit your controls something similar to

```
 <local:BaseExample  
 x:Class="child" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:local="YourAssembly"> </localBaseExample>
```

Comment: could you give me an example with creating a base control to put the dependency properties of the child in?

Answer (score 0):

Since routed events can bubble up the visual tree, take advantage of the `SelectionChanged` event from a `Selector`. I'm assuming two things:

- you're using a `ComboBox` (which derives from `Selector`)
- your child view is nested inside your parent view

if these assumptions are true, you could do something like this:

**Parent view**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Views.ParentView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Views">
    <!-- you can handle bubbled events outside the control of where it originated -->
    <Grid
        Selector.SelectionChanged="Grid_SelectionChanged">
        <v:ChildView
            x:Name="Child" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Parent view code behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Views
{
    public partial class ParentView : UserControl
    {
        public ParentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // because selectors allow multiple selections, a list is used.
            foreach (object selectedItem in e.AddedItems)
            {
                // do stuff with your selected items
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Child view**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Views.ChildView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```